# Debugging dll and sys from Kernel debugging Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windbg, windows-kernel

I need to break on already loaded dll functions. How can I do that? I tried the following things.
Name of dll: test.dll
Name of function: allocate()

```
bp test!allocate
bp allocate
```

I am using windbg, trying to debug kernel drivers. While doing kernel debugging , I also need to break into some user space dll functions, of which I have the code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up a breakpoint into device driver code (.sys) is easy, since loaded drivers are always mapped to system memory space. Breakpoints in process user space is a different story, because a particular memory range in user space might be paged out, or it might be mapped to user space of multiple processes (e.g. shared system dlls).

It is still possible to set a breakpoint into user space. You have to use an  *invasive* debugging ( /i ) option of `.process` command, as described in [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560042(v=vs.85).aspx). Once that is done, a command `bp /p` will start working that would allow you to set up a breakpoint into a process user space:

```
.process /i My_EPROCESS_block_address
g  $ <-- this command will break in few seconds
bp /p My_EPROCESS_block_address MyDll!MyFunction
```

While possible, debugging user process from kernel debugger is very inconvenient, because all user mode debugger extensions and many user mode commands would not work inside kernel debugger. It is faster and easier to launch a process you want to debug under user mode debugger. A coordination between kernel debugger and user mode debugger is as follows:

- When launching debugger use command line `ntsd -d`. The option `-d` makes ntsd to pipe input/output via kernel debugger, so you will see user mode debugger prompt (e.g. `0:000>` inside kernel debugger and can execute user mode debugger command).
- To break from user mode debugger into kernel mode debugger, type `.breakin`.
- To fall back into user mode debugger, type `g` from kernel mode prompt.

This works much easier, and all debugger extensions work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

if you have code sprinkling __debugbreak() in the code will get your code to break in kd at the right place

host `OS xpsp3` running on a `32bit processor`
guest `OS xp64` running inside `QEMU`
debugger `32bit windbg` on host
compiled as `x64` with`vs2k10express and 7.1 psdk toolset`

precompile dir contents

```
:dir /b
compile.bat
dbgbrk.cpp
```

source

```
:type dbgbrk.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define DBGBRK //comment this out to remove dbgspew
#ifdef DBGBRK
//using .ocommand mycommand in usermode windbg stacktrace will be printed out on break
#define DBRK  OutputDebugString("mycommand kb;"); __debugbreak();
#else
#define DBRK
#endif

int main (void)
{
    printf("hello we are debugging\n");
    DBRK
    printf("we broke in kd above\n");
    DBRK
    return 0;
}
```

bat file contents

```
:type compile.bat
IF %1 == "" goto usage
IFEXIST %1.cpp goto comlincpystr

:comlincpystr
@call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\setenv.cmd" /x64 /RELEAS
E

cl /c /Zi /nologo /W4 %1.cpp
link /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /nologo /RELEASE %1.obj

symstore add /f %1.exe /s f:\symbols /t "xp64" /v "vc2ktenexp_and_psdksevenpoint
one_toolset"
symstore add /f %1.pdb /s f:\symbols /t "xp64" /v "vc2ktenexp_and_psdksevenpoint
one_toolset"

copy %1.exe \\xp64\shared\. /y

goto exit

:usage

echo usage compile.bat <source.cpp>

:exit
```

post compile

```
:start compile.bat dbgbrk

:dir /b *.exe
dbgbrk.exe

:file dbgbrk.exe
dbgbrk.exe; PE32+ executable for MS Windows (console) Mono/.Net assembly

:
```

executing the executable promptly breaks in kd

```
kd> .lastevent
Last event: Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
  debugger time: Wed Jan 14 17:36:00.937 2015 
kd> lsa .
    10: 
    11: int main (void)
    12: {
    13:     printf("hello we are debugging\n");
>   14:     DBRK
    15:     printf("we broke in kd above\n");
    16:     DBRK
    17:     return 0;
    18: }

kd> uf @rip
dbgbrk!main+0x1d [dbgbrk.cpp @ 14]:
   14 00000001`4000101d cc              int     3
   15 00000001`4000101e 488d0df3120100  lea     rcx,[dbgbrk!__xt_z+0x50 (00000001`40012318)]
   15 00000001`40001025 e816000000      call    dbgbrk!printf (00000001`40001040)
   16 00000001`4000102a 488d0dff120100  lea     rcx,[dbgbrk!__xt_z+0x68 (00000001`40012330)]
   16 00000001`40001031 ff15c90f0100    call    qword ptr [dbgbrk!_imp_OutputDebugStringA (00000001`40012000)]
   16 00000001`40001037 cc              int     3
   17 00000001`40001038 33c0            xor     eax,eax
   18 00000001`4000103a 4883c428        add     rsp,28h
   18 00000001`4000103e c3              ret
kd> !dbgprint

mycommand kb;mycommand kb;
```